# How to fix 'React: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression'( state assignment)?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, expression, state, variable-assignment

I have news module that get articles from a link and spreads them in a state:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { URL } from '../../../config'

class NewsList extends Component {

    state = {
        items: [],
        start: this.props.start,
        amount: this.props.amount,
        end: this.props.start + this.props.amount

    }

    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get( `${ URL }/articles?_start=${ this.state.start }&end=${ this.state.end }` )
        .then( res => {
            this.setState( prevState => {
                items: [ ...prevState.items, ...res.items ]  
            } )
        } )
    }
    render() {
        return<div>
                news
            </div>
    }
}

export default NewsList
```

the error in the console:

```
Line 19:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

so looks its a simple mistake and it was not the same as similar questions with this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error happens because your call on setState requires a callback that returns a value. Your callback is not returning a value.

You should replace

```
this.setState( prevState => {
  items: [ ...prevState.items, ...res.items ]  
} )
```

With

```
this.setState( prevState => ({
  items: [ ...prevState.items, ...res.items ]  
}) )
```

Or with

```
this.setState( prevState => {
  return { items: [ ...prevState.items, ...res.items ]  }
} )
```

Comment: This gets rid of the error? I would have thought you'd have to return this.setState  to resolve the promise not just return the updater function.

Comment: @JoshPittman - `.then ( res => { ... })` is the last Promise in the chain. It can simply execute the function it wraps. Only need to return a Promise if chain to yet another Promise, that needs to wait on the result. So this is a "special case" for the last one in the chain. (At least that's how I understand it.)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your `setState` call inside the `axios.get` call. When you directly return an object in a arrow function, you have to wrap it with round brackets. Without the round brackets it is parsed as a function body.

From the documentation for ["Arrow functions - Returning object literals"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals):

> Keep in mind that returning object literals using the concise body syntax `params => {object:literal}` will not work as expected.
>
> This is because the code inside braces ({}) is parsed as a sequence of statements.
>
> Remember to wrap the object literal in parentheses.

```
// This will not work.
const () => { item: "Test" };

// This will work
const () => ({ item: "Test" });
```

Answer (score 2):

Prepend this.setState with a return statement or remove the redundant curly braces and you should be good.

```
.then( res => this.setState({items: [ ...this.state.items, ...res.items ]}))
```

Comment: tnx, Is it a safe method Not to use prevState?

Comment: It's definitely safe. Use the setState updater function when you want to prevent batching. The rest of the time it is simpler to just pass in an object. I explain this a bit better here https://worklog.svbtle.com/setState